# Array of Hashes, how to add new element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an element like this

```
customers =  [{ name: 'John Doe', age: 30, height: 175 }, { name: 'John Doe', age: 30, height: 175 } ... etc]
```

I know that this is a simple question, but how can I add another customer to this element. ie.

```
{name: 'Jane' , age: 25, height 150 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The manual probably helps: [Adding Items to Arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Adding+Items+to+Arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `shovel` method:

```
customers =  [{ name: 'John Doe', age: 30, height: 175 }, { name: 'John Doe', age: 30, height: 175 }]
new_customer = {name: 'Jane' , age: 25, height: 150 } 
customers << new_customer
 => [{:name=>"John Doe", :age=>30, :height=>175}, {:name=>"John Doe", :age=>30, :height=>175}, {:name=>"Jane", :age=>25, :height=>150}]
```

Comment: anddddddddddddddddddddd now i feel dumb for asking, thank you my friend.  I will accept when the time lets me.

Comment: The `any?` method seems like it would be the best for this case.
`costomers.any? {|customer| customer['name'] == "Jane"}`